# Simulation Error in Circuit Lab with 2 Dependent Sources

Tags: simulation, error, circuitlab

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fY3XKc.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I'm practicing some problems and came across this circuit.  It asks for the Thevenin equivalent with respect to terminals A and B.  I solved it by hand and have the correct answer and also verified it in the back of the book.

I wanted to simulate it in Circuit Lab to verify the results but I keep getting a simulation error.

[image: Simulation error message]

The text says:

```
Error building graph: TypeError: Cannot read property 'u' of undefined
Simulations will not run and values will not be displayed, until you return to Build mode and fix these errors.
```

Is there something blatant that I'm missing?  I've attached a picture of the circuit in the text book.

[image: image of question from text book]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(CircuitLab developer here.) Sorry for the cryptic error message. On CCCS1, you're specifying the control current as `R5` when it should be `R5.nA`. With this change, the simulation runs:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fIEbo8.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The `.nA` suffix is needed to uniquely specify the current going into a particular terminal of resistor R5. In this case, as drawn, it's the terminal on the left, so `R5.nA` picks up the current flowing left-to-right through R5, which matches your book's labeling for \$i_b\$.

See also [Labeling Voltages, Currents, and Nodes](https://ultimateelectronicsbook.com/labeling-voltages-currents-nodes/) (specifically the "Terminal Voltages and Currents" heading). And many more working CircuitLab examples with dependent sources on [Dependent (Controlled) Sources](https://ultimateelectronicsbook.com/dependent-sources/) and [Dependent Source Feedback](https://ultimateelectronicsbook.com/dependent-source-feedback/).